# screen-scraping iTunes Connect: Getting through login page

Tags: python, authentication, beautifulsoup, app-store-connect, screen-scraping

To perform screen-scraping upon **iTunes Connect** data, I am trying to get past its login using **Python**, **Requests**, **BeautifulSoup**.

This is **iTunes Connect** login page:
**https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static/login**

Typically, to begin screen-scraping upon other websites, I am able to get through the login by grabbing a **token** from webpage's hidden contents and then I am able to perform login with credentials allowing the website to think login request is coming through a valid browser.

For example, this has been my rough steps of performing login access using pseudo-python coding:

```
session = requests.Session()

response = session(GET, [URL LOGIN], ...)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
token_tag = soup.find_all(...)
TOKEN = token_tag.get(...)

response = session(POST, [URL LOGIN], [CREDENTIALS + TOKEN])
login_html = response.text
login_soup = BeautifulSoup(login_html, 'html.parser')
```

However, I am difficulty with iTune Connects' login.

Have others tried, and what is the trick?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing Python related, but I'd have a look at Fastlane/Spaceship: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane Pretty amazing stuff you can do with it and access iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm spit-balling here, but the problem is likely a lack of base64 encoding on the login credentials and token as they are passed on through the POST.

Your request should look like something along the lines of:

```
import requests
import base64

r = requests.post(<url login>, 
                headers={"Authorization": "Basic " + base64.b64encode(b'username:password'),
                data=payload)
```

Comment: can you please expand on what payload could look like in the context of iTunes connect?